# Ember CSP: Change connect-src dynamically

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Is there a way to change the connect-src at runtime in ember-cli-content-security-policy?

```
contentSecurityPolicy: {
            'default-src': "'none'",
            'script-src': "'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' www.google-analytics.com",
            'font-src': "'self' data: use.typekit.net fonts.gstatic.com",
            'img-src': "'self' data: image/png www.google-analytics.com",
            'connect-src': "'self' www.google-analytics.com wss://data-test/ws",
            'style-src': "'self' 'unsafe-inline' http://fonts.googleapis.com",
            'frame-src': "'self' http://test.com/ESTORERIA/Agreement/en/EULA.htm"
        }
```

Comment: Runtime changes probably not as that would probably invalidate the purpose of this if javascript could modify it on the user end. Could your changes be made at build time?

Comment: Better at runtime. Can it be changed via a config file?

Comment: You asked the same question in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-content-security-policy/issues/114) and got an answer there.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what values you want to include at build time you could do something in `environment.js` like:

```
contentSecurityPolicy: {
  'connect-src': process.env.CONTENT_SRC,
},
```

That would read this from your ENV variables so you could have the correct value set on whatever server you built your app on.